# How much time do you spend on moderating?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I recall hearing that a moderator should be willing to spend at least 30 minutes each (present) day on the site to moderate it.

If one considers to nominate himself/herself as moderator in an upcoming election -

- How much time should (s)he be willing to spend on the site each day to be a useful moderator?
- How much time do you moderators spend here in average?

Comment: about 9 hours on a daily basis. That's combined moderation + asking and answering. Can you link to the upcoming election youve mentioned?

Comment: It depends up to you, If it more than that, then It shows your interest to SO.

Comment: Entirely too much.

Comment: @mehow 9 hours a day? Seriously?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I think he just wants to be elected in the next run. :)

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Personally I think we ask too much of our moderators

Comment: @RichardTingle Most of the moderators do too much without actually being asked.  If anything I'd say that by an large they're expected to do less work than they actually do.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I *never* would have guessed that (says the pot...)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yea mon-friday if not too busy at work SO is all im doing. Not cause I am bored - it's because I am learning soooo much!

Comment: Actually Moderating (flag handling, general maintenance and cleanup etc) or just hanging around and looking at stuff? 'Cos I'm a mod on UX.SE and it's about 1% the former 99% the latter.

Comment: @mehow as a moderator or as a user? I don't know of many people who could get away from their day jobs enough to spend 9 hours a day on the network, and still be effective at both.

Comment: @AaronBertrand as a user. Yea there are not many jobs like mine i guess... I'd love to work for a company that utilizes my skills and teaches me more than just have me cause im 'good'...

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I disagree. There is no such thing as too much time put into moderation.

Answer (score 14):

It really is going to depend on the site and the volume.

I am a moderator on [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com), where volume is still low-moderate, and I spend between one and four hours a week dealing with flags, migrations and other moderation duties. On a typical week I likely spend more time answering questions (just like I did before I became a moderator).

On Stack Overflow, I think just by definition, I probably would have enough moderation duties to keep me busy enough to stop answering. This is just an assumption based on (a) the fact that most SO moderators do not answer many questions (at least that I see) and (b) the number of flags I raise on my own probably require a full-time moderator. :-)

Comment: Which makes me sad, that to be a moderator on SO you basically have to stop being a member

Comment: I think my experience bears out what you've said about Stack Overflow moderators. I've never been a very high volume poster, but moderating has definitely reduced how much I post by significant degree. I still *get* a lot of useful information, and occasionally leave helpful comments addressing questions, but answering is something that I tend only to do when I come across (via flags) questions I can help with, or when stalking the new questions on the 'Questions' tab.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sounds like more moderators are needed then. Seems a shame to draw talent away from the primary task of answering questions.

Comment: @Duncan I don't know. For me - and I suspect many others - it's a labor of love, and perhaps a bit of a 'graduation' of site activity. I'm not sure a higher quantity of moderators would be helpful overall. We tend to be a hard lot for the Community team to manage as-is. ;)

Comment: Oh; on the other hand, I definitely answer more questions *here*, on Meta. Though I've been active here for a bit, too.

Answer (score 13):

If you define moderating as spending time dealing with flags in the moderator queue, then I don't spend 30 minutes every day moderating Stack Overflow.  Somedays I'll spend an hour (or more) moderating (as a drive to clear out the moderator queue), some days I'll just moderate what I see on the front page or what I see organically from Google or Hacker News. Some days, the only things I do that could be considered 'moderator related' would be answering questions and participating here on Meta.

My participation ebbs and flows depending on my work schedule, my home schedule, and how burnt out by meta I feel that day (seriously, [meta is murder](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)).

I love moderating, and I love spending time learning from the community and helping to ascertain what the Stack Overflow community stands for, but my participation just depends on a day to day basis.  I think that is (and should be) normal, unless you're Bill the Lizard. That guy is an animal.

It definitely affects my question answering and asking. I find myself responding to questions by asking the OP for clarification or helping them improve their question, rather than just simply answering questions.  We've got a lot of people willing to answer questions, but not nearly as many people helping people understand why their questions need improvement.  I see the latter as a good place for me to step in.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the site. Usually, beta sites are very peaceful to moderate. When I started off on Chem, I was editing and commenting on every new untouched post, but there were only close to two a day. As time passed, the community started taking over, and now I just keep the queues clean and check on the main page; usually the editing and commenting gets handled before I get there.

These days I refresh Chem.SE twice or thrice per day, and usually there's not much to be done. Time spent moderating: 10 mins/day.

---

On sites like Physics, it gets harder. The mod queue usually is around 7 or so, but many flags are the type that we let sit for some time (waiting for the community to act). I personally leave a tab open the whole day and have periodic glances at the main page, along with the flag indicator. Most flags take a few seconds to handle, some take up to 10 minutes. We currently let the community handle the review queues, but I jump in every few days to reduce the load if the queues get large (this takes a while, because our posts tend to be on the verbose side).

A major part of my time is taken up by handling meta issues. Responding to requests on meta, starting new discussions, or steering ongoing ones, all of these take time.

I don't *always* do all this, depending on my schedule I may push off some of the work to the other mods.

Time spent moderating: 30 mins/day (distributed), when I'm not busy IRL.

---

These days I don't get much time to write answers on either site, so I only do so when I find a question that tickles my fancy. Otherwise I spend my time on SE by reading interesting posts and moderating.

Comment: "Usually, beta sites are very peaceful to moderate" HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!